# GKE Using gcePersistentDisk

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying trying to use a persistent disk from GCE on a GKE project.

Here are the steps I used:

gcloud compute disks create --size 50GB XXX

And here is the response:

---

WARNING: You have selected a disk size of under [200GB]. This may result in poor I/O performance. For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#performance.
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/zones/us-central1-a/disks/DISKNAME].
NAME               ZONE           SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
DISKNAME  us-central1-a  50       pd-standard  READY

New disks are unformatted. You must format and mount a disk before it
can be used. You can find instructions on how to do this at:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting

---

Here is a sniped of my deployment file:

---

volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/db
          name: GKEDISK
        - mountPath: /data/configdb
          name: GKEDISK
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: GKEDISK
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: DISKNAME

### fsType: ext4

Questions:

1) Do I need to format the disk myself or will GKE do this for me based on the fsType I selected?

2) After I create the disk, I can see it on gcloud, but kubectl get persistentvolumes returns "No Resources Found". Are there any extra steps that need to be execute to allow for GKE to see the disk created on GCE?

Answer (score 1):

If you go the manual route, you need to both create the disk in gcloud AND create PV in kubernetes.

Although, why not make use of the flexibility kube gives you with this cloud provider and stick with [dynamic PV provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) ? That way you just create a PVC and the volume/pv is created for you "magically".

Comment: Thank you @radek. I was trying to stay platform independent, but I see your point and am now switching over to dynamic PV provisioning. The strange thing is that even without creating the PV myself, the volume is attached on my pod and appear that the data I store there survives restarts.

Comment: You can define gcePersistentDisk inside of yor manifest volumes as you did, but this is in fact way less platform independent then using PVC. With PVC in default class, it's platform that is responsioble for providing storage. Even with manual provisioning (ie. some custom PVC class requirement) this is still better as you create your software and then in a separate process you can create PVs that support your services on this particular env

Comment: And equally as magically if you lose the PVC (ie by shutting down the GKE cluster for resource conservation or maintenance) then all your data is gone.

And yes you can back it all  up somewhere else and then have a process to restore from the last backup on redeployment. That is an awful lot more work.

For some deployments using an external gce disk is the most appropriate option.